# Change font size dynamically on ag-grid angularjs

Tags: angularjs, fonts, styles, size, ag-grid

I'm trying to enlarge the font on the ag-grid cell+header using cellClass, the sytax is:
... 
cellClass: cellStyling,
.....

```
function cellStyling(params){
    if(true){
        return {'FontSize': '96px', 'font-weight': 'bold'};
    } else {
        return {'FontSize': '16px','font-color':'green'};
    }
 }
```

//I've also tried:  return {'font-size': '96px', 'font-weight':....'};
//as well as ng-style on the ag-grid, I can change the color but font size does not change at all, has anyone had similar experience? This seems to be a common and easy thing to do on the ag-grid and I'm wondering if anyone has come up with good solution to share? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem but the following seems to work for **Angular2** implementation of ag-grid: ***ag-grid-ng2***

[ag-grid cell styling](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styling/)

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
this.columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'Site', field: "SiteID", width: 80, 
    cellStyle: function(params) {
      if (params.value=='AH') {
        return {color: 'red', 'font-size': '22px'};
      } else {
        return null;
        } 
    } },
  { headerName: 'Building', field: "Building", width: 300 }
  ... ]
```

In the html, this is applied to the ag-grid like so:

```
<ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 250px; " class="ag-fresh"
   [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
   [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
   [rowData]="buildings"
   ... >
```

Lastly, you should know that row-height defaults to 25px so a 96px font will disappear unless you also set row-heights as per the docs here:

[ag-grid row-height](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/)